# git merge branch, ignoring some commits

Tags: git, merge

I would like to merge branch A into branch B, however branch A has a few commits that delete files, which branch B needs. Using `git merge A` while on branch B only deletes the files. How can I merge branch A into B properly?

Comment: Do an interactive rebase instead, you can pick which commits to skip or squash. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: Do these specific commits only delete files or are there other changes in those commits? You can do as @jonrsharpe or alternatively you can cherry pick to select the exact commits you want `git cherry-pick <options-for-commits-you-want>` see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick for some decent examples (at the end)

Comment: @code_fodder good point; you can also edit specific commits during the rebase, so if there are any you want only part of that's also possible.

Comment: what happened is, B was created for some big changes, but we needed to merge changes - with some files removed, to A. Now when B is done, it should be merged into A, which may get changes in this time. If I merge B into A, those files will still be deleted won't they?

Comment: @tofiffe Yes, if in B you make some changes (and some of those changes are to remove files) then the merge will try to "apply" these changes. However if in A you have modified this files then you will get a conflict and you will be able to choose what you want to do about that.  How many files do you have like this? - a possible work around is to modify these files in A (add a space or something) and then the merge will conflict...  Or try the interactive rebase that jonrsharpe suggests? But if your file deletes are all in one commit (and no other changes in that commit) you can cherry pick.

Comment: One more solution. Create a new branch from A. Revert the unwanted commits. Merge the new branch to B. Solve conflicts if any.

Comment: this is the solution I've used, mind posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to have a merge commit in your history (e.g. to keep track of how information is moved around in your project), you can also use `git merge --no-ff --no-commit A`. This command will pause the merge process just before the commit is created, giving you a chance to check the code or apply some extra modifications to this commit.

You can then restore the deleted files using `git reset -- <file>` and `git checkout -- <file>`.